# How to receive user name and country with auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Good day Developers. Please i am new to react native and i want to use firebase auth for a project. But i don't know how to accept user name and country with the normal auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword method. Below is my code so far.. But it does work fine.

```js
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, View, Text, Alert } from 'react-native'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        login: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        Alert.alert(
            e.message);
          }
        },
        register: async (name, email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
            firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
      displayName: name
    });
            Alert.alert("Success ✅", "Account created successfully")
            return {};
          }
          catch (e) {
           
        Alert.alert(
            e.message  );
          }
        },
        


        forgot: async (email) => {
          try {
            await firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
            Alert.alert("Success ✅", "A Password Recorvery Link has been sent to your mail.")
          }
          catch (e) {
           
        Alert.alert(
            e.message  );
          }
        },

        logout: async () => {
          try {
            await auth().signOut();
          } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert(
            e.message  );
          }
        },

        sendver: async () => {
          try {
            await firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
          } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert(
            e.message  );
          }
        },

      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I will really appreaciate if anyone can help. thanks so much.

Comment: Firebase Auth does not store usernames or country of residence.  That's something you would have to store on your own, perhaps in a database.

Comment: Okay! So i have to create a database to store that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("abc@gmail.com", "******")
  .then(function(user) {
     // Success 
   })
.catch(function(error) {
    // Error Handling
});
```

> Note: Save user info on success in your database